# LoadError: incompatible library version: bindex/cruby

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4

**Ruby v2.4.1 - Rails v5.0.6**

After running `rake db:migrate`, this is the error I'm getting:

`LoadError: incompatible library version
.. /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bindex-0.5.0/lib/bindex/cruby.bundle`

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this with `gem pristine --all`, although strangely I had to do it a couple of times (*and restart the terminal*) in order for it to work.